# Can't Bake Texture, Diffuse and Normal Just Look Blank

Tags: uv, texture-baking, unity

I have this hammer that I plan on using in a Unity game. In order to do this I need to bake the texture but I can only get blank a blank diffuse and normal. I am using Blender 3 on Windows 10. I set the rendering to cycles GPU with Optix denoiser (I have a 3070). I tried to render a 4096 px image with alpha on the diffuse and no alpha on the normal. I even set the Normal image to non-color. Here are some pictures.

[image]
[image]

Here is the actual Blender File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hqf2HG6lq6YdMj2T-c2M2ObtuPfJdsDv/view?usp=sharing

Here are the texture:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XHh4sbQa0iVhvGyEFf0HLhvYtJNSziYA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, it would help if you packed all the useful textures in the file itself

Comment: Oh my bad I tried to pack the textures into the file in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fs2tTD4yTaz7SElUauCuUwkjTPttle2g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've duplicated the hammer, unwrap (Smart UV Project) and bake the Diffuse with the Selected to Active option, it seems to work: https://i.postimg.cc/jj6zJH34/1.jpg

Comment: it also works if I bake to itself, except I guess you need to create a new UV map (unwrap with the Smart UV Project) so that the result doesn't overlap

Comment: What! This is amazing how did you do that? Can you send me the file with the new baked texture?

Comment: Duplicate your hammer but keep it at the same place, unwrap the copy with the Smart UV Project option, delete its materials, give it a new one, in this material create an Image Texture with a new image called Bake for example (or Diffuse), select the original hammer, shift select the copy, go into the Render panel, choose Bake Type > Diffuse, enable Influence > Color only, enable the Selected to Active option, press Bake, and so on for the other textures you want. https://i.postimg.cc/kGjxj7W1/Diffuse.png

Comment: Moonboots you are a genius! It's almost completely working now. The only problem that I still have is that I baked everything except for the Hammer Head's normal. Check out these images. Notice everything is baked perfectly both the diffuse and normal except for the Hammer Head's normals. Diffuse: https://imgur.com/a/I4IOlYh Normal: https://imgur.com/a/SYy5fRw

Comment: And here's the Blender File in it's current state. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iaMyv5D8aKdK4GLjJimRX61Q21Ijcz4c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't see any bump on the hammer's head, so what normal is the low-poly supposed to bake?

Comment: The first pic is the hammer head with the old texture and the second is the hammer with the new baked texture. Notice how the new one is sleek black without any of the pac marks. First texture: https://imgur.com/a/hwfC5yf Second Baked Texture: https://imgur.com/a/AhXQhLO